# There was issue parsing the XML in this Document Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xml, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i have started new tutorial to build Xamarin.IOS app.
after adding a single view IOS app and trying to opening a Main.Storyboard or LaunchScreen.storyboard i have encounter the following error

> There was a problem parsing The XML in this document

```
    System.NotSupportedException: Could not parse xml ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.GetCurrentXcodeVersion () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:851 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.get_XcodeVersion () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:160 
  at MonoTouch.Design.IModelObjectContextExtensions.WithIdProvider (MonoTouch.Design.IModelObjectContext context, MonoTouch.Design.IIdProvider idProvider) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/IModelObjectContextExtensions.cs:10 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElementsAndAttributes (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x0003d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:278 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result, Xamarin.Designer.ProxiedException error) [0x000d0] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:370 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00041] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:245 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElement (MonoTouch.Design.LayoutGuides layoutGuides, MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:1019 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:313 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElements (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x000da] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:324 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElementsAndAttributes (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:274 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result, Xamarin.Designer.ProxiedException error) [0x000d0] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:370 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00041] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:245 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElement (MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedViewController model, MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x000f3] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:751 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:313 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElements (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x000da] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:324 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElementsAndAttributes (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:274 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result, Xamarin.Designer.ProxiedException error) [0x000d0] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:370 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00041] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:245 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElement (MonoTouch.Design.Scene scene, MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x0008b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:689 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:313 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElements (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x000da] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:324 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElementsAndAttributes (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:274 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result, Xamarin.Designer.ProxiedException error) [0x000d0] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:370 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00041] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:245 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElement (MonoTouch.Design.Storyboard sb, MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00040] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:884 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.Parse (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Boolean skipImageGeneration) [0x00021] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:225 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.Parse (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:214 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.Parse (System.Xml.Linq.XElement xml, MonoTouch.Design.DeviceFamily targetRuntime, MonoTouch.Design.IModelObjectContext modelObjectContext) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:203 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession+<LoadXml>d__163.MoveNext () [0x00130] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/b604c37c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:412
```

i have been search around to found the way to fix this issue but no luck 
i have found the following

1. [Storyboard: Problem Parsing the XML in this document](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44556/storyboard-problem-parsing-the-xml-in-this-document)
2. [There was a problem rendering this document" when opening iOS Designer, "Could not parse xml" in logs](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/89193/error-when-openning-ios-designer.html)

but i am stilling facing the issue 
for more information i am running visual studio community V7.2.2 build 11 and Xcode 9.1(9B55) on Macbook pro

PS. i have not added or removed anything form Main.storyboard xml document , the main and launch screen storyboard do open on Xcode

```
    <?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="11134" systemVersion="15F34" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="11106" />
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0" />
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModuleProvider="" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ" />
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE" />
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667" />
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES" />
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB" />
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder" />
            </objects>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Have you tried to create an empty storyboard to see if it could be able to open ?

Comment: i have but no luck